# Custom URL in facebook and twitter share button

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to share a particular link when clicked on a share button in my app.
Facebook share button snipet

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(location.href), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

How do i input my custom url?

Comment: Have you tried changing `location.href`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `location.href` to whatever URL you want to share.

For example:

```
<a href="#" 
  onclick="
    window.open(
      'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent('http://google.com'), 
      'facebook-share-dialog', 
      'width=626,height=436'); 
    return false;">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: thanks that worked but it has a minor error, the link should be specified in '' and not "", as it gives a error about unexpected token }

Comment: "Welcome to SO.  If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer).  That does two things.  It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist.  See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716) for a full explanation"

Comment: @Shadowfax totally forgot to give it a tick :P, mistake rectified.